# How to make grid items leave no white space in between?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tailwind-css, css-grid

[**For Image**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qwGnl.png)

In the aboveimage there's ***ghost space between second grid-item and fifth grid-item*** I was wondering are there any solutions for this using ***tailwindcss***

my code :

```
 <div className='grid grid-cols-3 grid-rows-3   grid-flow-dense gap-4 mt-10'>
        {skills.map((skill, idx) => {
          return (
            <div
              key={idx}
              className='flex flex-col col-span-1 h-fit items-center justify-center gap-3 bg-white px-6 py-4 rounded-xl'>
              <h4 className='font-bold text-xl'>{skill.title}</h4>
              <div className='flex flex-wrap gap-2'>
                {skill.tags.map((tag, idx) => (
                  <p
                    key={idx}
                    className='flex-grow text-[16px] border-[1px] px-2 py-2 border-spacing-2 border-black  mr-2'>
                    {tag}
                  </p>
                ))}
              </div>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
```

I tried using `grid-flow-dense` in code thought it might work but sadly didn't .

Comment: Have you tried changing `gap-4` to `gap-0`? https://tailwindcss.com/docs/gap

Comment: @ray no I meant the ghost space between grids as shown in the image

Comment: Oh. You're looking for a [masonry layout](https://css-tricks.com/piecing-together-approaches-for-a-css-masonry-layout/). CSS [columns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/columns) might be the most [straightforward solution](https://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/NeRNBO).

Comment: fwiw: [googling "tailwind masonry"](https://www.google.com/search?q=tailwind+masonry) turns up some possible solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your grid is working as it should. grid-flow-dense just means it will try and fit in grid items in open spaces when you use items that span multiple columns etc. See it working below.

[image: grid item as you expect]

Remote `h-fit` (to fill the space as expected) and `justify-center` (to not have the content horizontally aligned in the middle.

[image: working as expected]

Comment: OP wants the vertical space between the middle cell’s content and the one above it collapsed.